# Rounding up to 3 decimal points just truncates the rest

Tags: bash

```
read n
i=0
sum=0
while [ $i -lt $n ]
do
    read X
    sum=`expr $X + $sum `
    i=`expr $i + 1 `
done
echo "scale = 3; $sum/$n" | bc -l
```

--my above code is rounding upto a lesser value, where i want the greater one
e.g. if the ans is 4696.9466 it is rounding up to 4696.946 whereas 4696.947 is what i want. So , suggest any edits

Comment: Could be caused by you truncating instead of rounding...

Answer (score 0):

You may pipe your `bc` to `printf` :

```
echo "scale = 4; $sum/$n" | bc -l | xargs printf '%.*f\n' 3
```

From you example :

```
$ echo "scale = 4; 4696.9466" | bc -l | xargs printf '%.*f\n' 3
4696,947
```

Comment: no still coming down to same result when i use the variables

Comment: The scale must be equal to `4`. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Change last line of your script from `echo "scale = 3; $sum/$n" | bc -l` to

```
printf %.3f $(echo "$sum/$n" | bc -l)
```

`printf` will round it off correctly. For example,

```
$ sum=1345
$ n=7
$ echo "$sum/$n" | bc -l
192.14285714285714285714

$ printf %.3f $(echo "$sum/$n" | bc -l)
192.143
```

Comment: :) My pleasure. If it works, please accept the answer. Accepting an answer informs other users that the issue is resolved.